# Outlook 2016 not loading add in icons

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are currently working with a prospect to pilot an Outlook Web Add-in for email compose mode. Problem is that the buttons of our add appear BUT the PNG icons for the buttons are not loaded. The only icon loaded is the one displayed in Outlook ‘Add In Management’ (HighResolutionIconUrl).

Tested versions:

- Outlook 2016 (16.0.4966.1000) MSO 16.0.4939.1000
- Exchange 2016 (15.1.1913.7)
- IE: Version 11.864.17763.0

The add in is working properly at other customers and on our test infrastructure (even tested on the same server/client combination the prospect is using: Exchange 2016 but also Exchange Online in combination with Outlook 2016 and 2019 for Windows and MAC + OWA).

We think we did everything described in the FAQs and troubleshooting guides and what we found during our research:

- Checked that the icons can be opened by the customer via browser
- Client cache (content inside of %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF) has been deleted before each test and Outlook has been restarted.
- Add in ID and release number have been changed for each test cycle
- Icon names have been changed on Web Server side and accordingly in manifest
- Do not send any no-cache/no-store headers back from the Web Server
- Checked if icons of other add ins are displayed: The ribbon icon of another add-in came up once but disappeared after the cache has been deleted to prepare the next test. Afterwards it appeared only some days later. So it seems that there is a very long duration between installation and visibility of icons. But this was the only add-in where we managed to let the icons appear. Even after taking over nearly all of the manifest parameters (even placing the icon on the same instance) the icon does not appear for our add-in.

FYI: Due to customer policy the add in has been deployed centrally by the Exchange admin.

Question is what would be the best next step to evaluate the problem? We would very much appreciate some ideas/guidance on how we can identify what is going on at the moment when Outlook should load the icons for the add-in?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>5fcfef62-0054-4250-92e3-5adccd871b55</Id>

  <Version>4.0.0.5</Version>
  <ProviderName>Provider Sample</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-In Name Example T13" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Add-In Name Example T13"/>

  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-full.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-full.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://<domain>.com" />

  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html?ilnk=25041931"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>


  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
    <!-- Rule    -->    
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

<!-- VersionOverrides for the v1.0 schema -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Message compose form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Check Email Button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="provideButton">
                  <Label resid="provideButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="provideButtonTitle" />
                    <Description resid="provideButtonTitleDesc" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="providePane" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="providePane" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html?ilnk=25041931"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-In Example T13"/>
        <bt:String id="provideButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Button1"/>
        <bt:String id="provideButtonTitle" DefaultValue="Button1"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="provideButtonTitleDesc" DefaultValue="Add-In Name Example T13"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <!-- VersionOverrides for the v1.1 schema -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- Message compose form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Check Email Button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="provideButton">
                  <Label resid="provideButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="provideButtonTitle" />
                    <Description resid="provideButtonTitleDesc" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="providePane" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/assets/pticon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="providePane" DefaultValue="https://<domain>.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html?ilnk=25041931"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-In Example T13"/>
        <bt:String id="provideButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Button1"/>
        <bt:String id="provideButtonTitle" DefaultValue="Button1"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="provideButtonTitleDesc" DefaultValue="Add-In Name Example T13"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Problem has been partly solved. We found out that the add-in icons are loaded for some of the others and others not. We are still investigating the issue and I will update this post as soon as we have made further findings.

Comment: Check to see if there is an attempt to retrieve the icons by looking at a Fiddler trace or F12/Network.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, we are currently checking if we are able to check with Fiddler. For the moment we are still evaluating the reasons why the icons are visible on one of the test users laptop.

Comment: Can also check the working laptop with Fiddler to see if it requested the icons.  If using Outlook desktop, the icons could be in the Outlook desktop cache -- could try with a browser instead with the browser file cache cleared.

Comment: Seems like this investigation is on the right track (definitely worth checking a network trace). For users who don't see any icons, one other potential cause came up a couple of months ago. The "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" setting in IE can prevent the icons from being cached. More info about that issue here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/396